# Django project with gunicorn server on Heroku does not serve static files

Tags: django, heroku, gunicorn, static-files

My Django 1.3 project serves the static files on a development server but with the gunicorn server static files are not served. I followed the steps of [this Heroku guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django#using-a-different-wsgi-server).

When I used the contents of my procfile like in the guide (
`web: gunicorn myproject_django.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT`) my project was not recognised by Heroku.

Then I changed that Procfile to this:

```
web: python myproject_django/manage.py run_gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT -w 3
```

Now my app runs except for the static files(css not active nor images).

**My project tree:**

```
.
├── Procfile
├── myproject_django
│   ├── core
│   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── static
│   │   │   ├── css
│   │   │   │   ├── base.css
│   │   │   │   ├── layout.css
│   │   │   │   
│   │   │   └── media
│   │   │       ├── pek.ico
│   │   │       ├── pek.png
│   │   │       ├── pek_symbol.png
│   │   ├── tests.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── manage.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── core
│   │       ├── home.html
│   │       └── install.html
│   └── urls.py
└── requirements.txt
```

**Potentially relevant parts of settings.py**

```
MEDIA_ROOT = ''

MEDIA_URL = '/static/media'

STATIC_ROOT = ''

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.abspath(__file__)+'/..'+'/myproject_django/core/static', 
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)


INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'core',
    'gunicorn',
    'django.contrib.admin',
)
```

### Edit

I adjusted the following things after Francis Yaconiello's entry:

**In settings.py**

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'core/static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = ( os.path.abspath(__file__)+'/..'+'/core/static', )
```

**In gitignore:**

```
staticfiles/*
```

Then commited.
And finally ran `heroku run python myproject_django/manage.py collectstatic`.

But static files are still not served when I check the webpage.
Given my directory tree why didn't these changes work?

### Edit2

I still don't see my static files. When I click on an image while `DEBUG=True` I get this:

```
Request URL: http://myproject.herokuapp.com/static/media/pek.png
```

**Tree** (Note that the `staticfiles` dir is empty)

```
.
├── Procfile
├── myproject_django
│   ├── admin
│   ├── core
│   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── static
│   │   │   ├── css
│   │   │   │   ├── base.css
│   │   │   │   ├── layout.css
│   │   │   └── media
|   |   |       ├── pek.ico
|   │   │       ├── pek.png
|   │   │       ├── pek_symbol.png
│   │   ├── tests.py
│   │   ├── views.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── manage.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── staticfiles
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── core
│   │       ├── 404.html
│   │       ├── 500.html
│   │       ├── home.html
│   │       └── install.html
│   ├── urls.py
└── requirements.txt
```

**In settings.py**

```
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'static/media')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH,'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'core/static'),
)
```

Answer (score 5):

Specify your `STATIC_ROOT`

I generally set it to :

```
import os
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "staticfiles")
```

create that directory in your project

```
mkdir staticfiles
```

make sure that the contents of staticfiles is not git tracked

```
nano .gitignore
```

add

```
staticfiles/*
```

then commit it and push to heroku.

lastly,

```
heroku run python manage.py collectstatic
```

## EDIT

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'core/static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = ( os.path.abspath(__file__)+'/..'+'/core/static', )
```

These two settings cannot be the same thing.

`STATICFILES_DIR` is OK, if redundant your `STATICFILES_FINDERS` already is telling it to find staticfiles in the `static` directory of each app with this: `'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',`

The point of `STATIC_ROOT` is to provide a new directory completely separate from your project that you can serve with a third party server like nginx. Which is why you created that directory `staticfiles`:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'staticfiles')
```

## ANOTHER EDIT

workaround for ephemeral filesystem

> Each dyno gets its own ephemeral filesystem, with a fresh copy of the most recently deployed code. During the dyno’s lifetime its running processes can use the filesystem as a temporary scratchpad, but no files that are written are visible to processes in any other dyno and any files written will be discarded the moment the dyno is stopped or restarted.

which means that as long as you collectstatic on each dyno instance during web startup, you won't have any issues.

```
web: python myproject_django/manage.py collectstatic --noinput; python myproject_django/manage.py run_gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT -w 3
```

That said, I currently use S3 and django storages http://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html. Its fairly easy (and cheap) to get this going.

Comment: I changed some things after your answer, Could you check the edit of the original post?

Comment: check it out again, i added some explanations.

Comment: once you changed your STATIC_ROOT did you `heroku run python manage.py collectstatic` ? could you add the output of collectstatic?

Comment: won't work with heroku, cf. [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#isolation-and-security), also just answered @Bentley4 's other question http://stackoverflow.com/a/12014658/343834

Comment: In the past I ran collectstatic as part of my web worker startup (in the procfile) so anytime a webworker was starting or restarting it would collect my static files leading to my not being inconvenienced by the ephemeral filesystem. I would actually recommend S3 and the django storages app (use S3 Boto) for getting past this.

Comment: After trying everything, nothing worked, until you gave me the idea of restarting the dyno. Thanks, it works now.

Comment: wow this is old, is hosting django sites with heroku still a PIA?

Answer (score 4):

There is one solution.

In urls.py add:

```
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns += patterns('',
    (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
)
```

p.s. For `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`

Answer (score 1):

Use the `run_collectstatic` script which run as part of the `post_compile` provided by [heroku-django-cookbook](https://github.com/nigma/heroku-django-cookbook). It makes use of the `post_compile` hook provided by the Heroku python buildpack

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem; it seems you need these three settings in particular:

1. `STATIC_ROOT` must be defined in your `settings.py`, for example:

   ```
   STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'served/static/')
   ```

   Where `PROJECT_PATH` is your project root (in your case, the absolute path to the `myproject_django` directory.
2. Similarly, `STATIC_URL` must also be set (Django will throw an ImproperlyConfigured error anyway, if you don't). Your current setting of `'/static/'` is fine.
3. In your root `urls.py`, configure the static urls:

   ```
   from django.conf import settings
   from django.conf.urls.static import static  

   ...

   urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
   ```

Finally, run `python manage.py collectstatic`; this will copy all the files from `/path/to/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/` to `/served/static/`. (You can read more about how Django serves static files [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/)).

Now when you run `foreman start`, you should see the admin with styling.

Don't forget to add `served/static/` to your `.gitignore`!

Answer (score 0):

I found [here](http://www.realpython.com/blog/python/migrating-your-django-project-to-heroku/) good way to resolve all my problems with Django on heroku