# Heroku deployment using django and gunicorn: Missing gunicorn_django file or dir

Tags: python, django, heroku, gunicorn

[This blog](http://elweb.co/programacion/django-static-files-on-heroku/) advises to put the following in my `Procfile`.

```
web: python myproject_django/manage.py collectstatic --noinput; bin/gunicorn_django --workers=4 --bind=0.0.0.0:$PORT myproject_django/settings.py
```

But running my project on Heroku fails. This is from `$ Heroku logs`:

```
app[web.1]: bash: bin/gunicorn_django: No such file or directory
```

So there is a `gunicorn_django` file/dir missing. What should that file/dir contain and where should I put it?

**Tree**

```
.
├── Procfile
├── myproject_django
│   ├── admin
│   ├── core
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── manage.py
│   ├── project_static
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── templates
│   ├── urls.py
└── requirements.txt
```

### Edit

When I change my `Procfile` to `web: python myproject_django/manage.py run_gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT -w 3` my project runs fine(also serving static files).

When I then push to heroku, and do `heroku run python myproject_django/manage.py collectstatic` and then `heroku open`, then my site is being served except for the static files.

**Tree** (Note that the `staticfiles` dir is empty)

```
.
├── Procfile
├── myproject_django
│   ├── admin
│   ├── core
│   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── static
│   │   │   ├── css
│   │   │   │   ├── base.css
│   │   │   │   ├── layout.css
│   │   │   └── media
|   |   |       ├── pek.ico
|   │   │       ├── pek.png
|   │   │       ├── pek_symbol.png
│   │   ├── tests.py
│   │   ├── views.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── manage.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── staticfiles
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── core
│   │       ├── 404.html
│   │       ├── 500.html
│   │       ├── home.html
│   │       └── install.html
│   ├── urls.py
└── requirements.txt
```

**In settings.py**

```
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'static/media')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH,'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'core/static'),
)
```

### Edit2 (To Maxime R.)

Starting from the setup in the first edit, I ran `python myproject_django/manage.py collectstatic`, then pushed to heroku. `heroku open` still does not serve the static files.
Clicking on an image while `DEBUG=True` returns a 404 error: `request url: http://myproject_django.herokuapp.com/static/media/pyk1.png`.

### Edit3 (To Maxime R.)

**heroku logs**

```
2012-08-18T10:18:37+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2012-08-18T10:18:37+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2012-08-18T10:18:38+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python myproject_django/manage.py run_gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:47262 -w 3`
2012-08-18T10:18:39+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/myproject_django
2012-08-18T10:18:39+00:00 app[web.1]: STATIC_ROOT: /app/myproject_django/staticfiles
2012-08-18T10:18:39+00:00 app[web.1]: STATICFILES_DIRS: '/app/myproject_django/core/static'
2012-08-18T10:18:39+00:00 app[web.1]: STATIC_ROOT: /app/myproject_django/staticfiles
2012-08-18T10:18:39+00:00 app[web.1]: STATICFILES_DIRS: '/app/myproject_django/core/static'
2012-08-18T10:18:39+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/myproject_django
2012-08-18T10:18:39+00:00 app[web.1]: 2012-08-18 05:18:39 [2] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 0.14.6
2012-08-18T10:18:39+00:00 app[web.1]: 2012-08-18 05:18:39 [2] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:47262 (2)
2012-08-18T10:18:39+00:00 app[web.1]: 2012-08-18 05:18:39 [2] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2012-08-18T10:18:39+00:00 app[web.1]: 2012-08-18 05:18:39 [5] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 5
2012-08-18T10:18:39+00:00 app[web.1]: 2012-08-18 05:18:39 [6] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 6
2012-08-18T10:18:39+00:00 app[web.1]: 2012-08-18 05:18:39 [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
2012-08-18T10:18:39+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/myproject_django/app/myproject_django
2012-08-18T10:18:39+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/myproject_django
2012-08-18T10:18:39+00:00 app[web.1]: STATICFILES_DIRS: '/app/myproject_django/core/static'
2012-08-18T10:18:39+00:00 app[web.1]: STATIC_ROOT: /app/myproject_django/staticfilesSTATIC_ROOT: /app/myproject_django/staticfiles
2012-08-18T10:18:39+00:00 app[web.1]: STATICFILES_DIRS: '/app/myproject_django/core/static'
2012-08-18T10:18:39+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-08-18T10:18:39+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-08-18T10:18:39+00:00 app[web.1]: STATICFILES_DIRS: '/app/myproject_django/core/static'
2012-08-18T10:18:39+00:00 app[web.1]: STATIC_ROOT: /app/myproject_django/staticfiles
2012-08-18T10:18:40+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2012-08-18T10:18:40+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2012-08-18T10:18:41+00:00 app[web.1]: 2012-08-18 05:18:41 [7] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7)
2012-08-18T10:18:41+00:00 app[web.1]: 2012-08-18 05:18:41 [2] [INFO] Handling signal: term
2012-08-18T10:18:41+00:00 app[web.1]: 2012-08-18 05:18:41 [6] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 6)
2012-08-18T10:18:41+00:00 app[web.1]: 2012-08-18 05:18:41 [5] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 5)
2012-08-18T10:18:41+00:00 app[web.1]: 2012-08-18 05:18:41 [2] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2012-08-18T10:18:42+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2012-08-18T10:18:43+00:00 heroku[router]: GET myproject.herokuapp.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=36ms status=200 bytes=5474
2012-08-18T10:18:43+00:00 heroku[router]: GET myproject.herokuapp.com/static/media/pek.png dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=16ms status=404 bytes=2613
```

Answer (score 3):

The blog post you refers to dates back to november 2011 when the virtualenv was installed in `/app`. The [new style virtualenv](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/commit/6aadf1683a2e2a3f9cca1ea90cf74bf809214328) commit moved the virtual env from `/app` to `/app/.heroku/venv`.

This explains your initial error, `/app/.heroku/venv/bin/gunicorn_django` should exist.

**This is bad practice:**

You won't succeed to durably collect static files by collecting them after the push. Read the doc, especially the [ephemeral filesystem part](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#isolation-and-security): `collectstatic` and `open` run in two different dynos, what's collected in the first won't be available to the second thus explaining the inconsistencies you pointed in your edit.

It only works if you collect files *and* launch the server in the same `[web]` process but then it would recollect all static files every time the dyno is restarted. Just feels like bad design.

Either:

- collect your static files before pushing to heroku
- use another solution (like S3 even if the purpose of the blog post was not to use it)

Anyways, serving static assets with an elegant and efficient workflow ain't easy.

IMHO, better to stick with one command per process in `Procfile`, I'll suggest you start scripting your deploys if you want to chain commands.

Comment: Nice, this explains a lot. I tried your first solution(collect your static files before pushing to heroku). It did not work, see Edit2 of the original post. Also check my answer to Dean Elbaz how I called the static files from the template.

Comment: Did you commit the changes after collecting the static files ?

Comment: So should I delete the workers and reinitiate them? How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

make sure you have gunicorn as an installed app in settings.py.

and try running:

> `python my_project/manage.py run_gunicorn <options>`

Comment: gunicorn is set as an installed app in settings.py. Just running 
`python my_project/manage.py run_gunicorn` runs fine. But when I try the same on heroku: 
`heroku run python myproject_django/manage.py run_gunicorn` I get a `could not connect` error when going to the url in my browser.

Comment: That looks like a configuration issue. Could you make it run locally? are you using a reverse proxy like ngnix or lighttpd? (I don't know anything about your project, but if you want it to scale well, you should)
And what error do you get? 500? 404?

Comment: Check the Edit of the original post

Comment: and how are you calling the static files from the template?

Comment: For css: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% load static %}{% get_static_prefix %}css/base.css" />`. For images like so `<img width="65px;" src="static/media/pek.png" alt="" id="symbol" />`